# How to load System.js modules with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, systemjs

I'm trying to get TypeScript working with the default Aurelia skeleton, which is based on System.JS as a loader.

I'm having trouble getting TypeScript to accept module imports. I renamed one of the skeleton files, "nav-bar.js" to "nav-bar.ts" to see if I could convert the example into TypeScript. The code results in a compiler error: "Error:(5, 24) TS2307: Cannot find external module 'aurelia-framework'."

```
import {bindable} from "aurelia-framework";

export class NavBar {
  //noinspection ES6Validation
  @bindable router = null;
}
```

How can I get TypeScript to see the aurelia-framework as a valid import? There's a file in the root of the project called config.js that seems to describe the specific location of "aurelia-framework" but TypeScript doesn't know how to load it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use `d.ts` definition files for registration with TypeScript Definitely Typed registry for use with tsd package manager. You can find different implementations on github, for example [here](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/aurelia-definitely-typed) or [here](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript). Also this [tutorial](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/05/06/getting-started-with-aurelia-and-typescript/) might be useful.

Comment: To add, we will be adding official `.d.ts` files in our next set of major releases.

Comment: The links have useful info - there's apparently a tsconfig.json file that I think defines locations like "aurelia-framework". However, the links you've provided have definitions that precedes the latest Aurelia release on June 9th. Is someone planning to update the definitions to the current Aurelia release? Or should I be using the old definitions?